# Renko function in TradingView

Tags: pine-script

[Update] modified the chart to use on line close. Highlighted the displacement between the signal and its renko calculation (see picture).

I have a chart in trading view (https://www.tradingview.com/chart/Zc3W7B8I/) that uses the function renko to overlay the renko open and the close on any desired time frame.

As you can see on the picture, the actual renko values seem to be displaced compared where the threshold is actually violated and hence a new bar is created.

Could somebody please point me in the direction where I can find how TradingView calculates this particular function? For the record I have used and coded renko before but this is a first for me.

Thank you

```
//@version=4
strategy("Renko Plot Strat", overlay=true)
size=input(1)
renko_tickerid = renko(syminfo.tickerid, "Traditional", size)
renko_close = security(renko_tickerid, "1", close)
renko_open = security(renko_tickerid, "1", open)


plot(renko_close, color=renko_close > renko_open?color.lime:color.fuchsia)
plot(renko_open, color=renko_close > renko_open?color.lime:color.fuchsia)
```

[image: Offset on Renko]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Renko function seems to be delayed by one brick, which is hard to debug intuitively because one brick represents a random period of time.

This seems to be a separate issue from the fact that it does not display bricks until they are confirmed. A close that should form a new brick will render a new brick in the function until the time that the function formed the next brick.

I hope to be corrected if I'm wrong, but I did the following (I'm only tracking renko close levels, not open) to use the renko function settings with up-to-date bricks.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © bajaco

//@version=4
study("renko test again", overlay=true)
renko_tickerid = renko(syminfo.tickerid, "ATR", 14)
renko_close = security(renko_tickerid, timeframe.period, close)
renko_open = security(renko_tickerid, timeframe.period, open)
var float brick_size = abs(renko_close - renko_open)
var float previous_close = renko_open
var float real_renko = renko_close

green = real_renko > previous_close
if green and close - real_renko >= brick_size
    previous_close := real_renko
    real_renko := real_renko + floor((close- real_renko)/brick_size) * brick_size
else if not green and close - real_renko >= brick_size*2
    real_renko := real_renko + floor((close- real_renko)/brick_size) * brick_size
else if not green and real_renko - close >= brick_size
    previous_close := real_renko
    real_renko := real_renko - floor((real_renko - close)/brick_size) * brick_size
else if green and real_renko - close >= brick_size*2
    real_renko := real_renko - floor((real_renko - close)/brick_size) * brick_size

plot(real_renko, linewidth=2, color=color.black, style=plot.style_stepline)
bgcolor(real_renko > previous_close ? color.green : color.red)
```

Edit, removed resetting the previous_close when it's changing direction, this would accurately display the open level now.

Comment: I've been trying to find this for 3 days! Why would they have the renko function lagging? Btw, this only is affecting backtesting, real time data works fine! Wtf!

Answer (score 1):

The `security()` call will only show Renko values once the formation of a new brick is completed.

These Help Center pages explain how Renko charts are calculated:
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000480330/
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502284/
https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481040/

Comment: thank you for your response. I have updated the picture with a better representation of the issue I see. I had already found the links but they only refer to actual renko bars and not the overlay on top of another timeframe, so it is not clear if the actual renko charts will experience the same issue. thanks again